# C++ Link Error Mangling when trying to put in .a

Tags: c++, ios4

Have been using some c / c++ code for quite a while and it has been working fine in a project.  Now trying to make a .a from the code and all is well except for one item.

There is a c routine, let call it

```
void init(sometype *)
```

This is marked as a c++ file in XCODE and it has a .h file

In there we have

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"
{
#endif

void init(sometype *);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

All of this links find when calling from an objective C when linking all as one app

When this code is included in a .a and then trying to link from a separate project we are getting....

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "__Znam", referenced from:
      _init in libMy.a(Objectfile.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It looks like we are getting some C++ init routine?  The .o when it links find looks the same as when we compile for the .a (__Znam is in there).

So what lib is missing ????

Will do some more digging to try and find out what is not being included behind the scenes.

---------- New Information ------------

Well it looks like the problem is that the "new" keyword is not working in this routine and this is probably the routined that is not getting linked in properly.

So a line like...

```
var->output = new Int32*[10];
```

Is not working properly. .....

Comment: You need the run-time library that is referenced from init() in libMy.a? Your C linker might do this automatically. You could check a sample .map file where __Znam is defined when you you have linked a C project successfully.

Comment: Well, libMy.a has multiple .o in there and they all look correct and I am linking against libMy.a.  It seems somehow that the routine is being found in a .a that is not being supplied in the test app.  I agree with your trying to find the routine in the working one.  Just thought that someone might have seen this before.